# lambda capture fails (on MSVC) if object has no copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

[Code to reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/4cKn8Y):

```
struct S
{
    S();
    S(S const&) = delete;
};

auto x = [s = S()]{};
```

It looks like MSVC doesn't apply (mandatory in C++17?) copy elision when building lambda. This breaks some of my code...

Does VC's behavior violate standard?

Comment: Are you compiling with MSVC in C++17 mode?

Comment: @C.M. The copy constructor must be available for the copy elision.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow by curiosity, why?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo To make the copy elision. Otherwise the object is uncopyable..

Comment: @Eljay yes (check godbolt snippet).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Afaik, it is no longer required since C++17

Comment: @C.M. that's what I also thought... For me, MSVC is wrong on giving error... but not sure.

Comment: @C.M. Can you provide a reference to the Standard  that confirms this.

Comment: Interesting, [C2280](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?view=vs-2019).  Might want to add the `language-lawyer` tag.  (If I make the copy constructor implicitly deleted rather than explicitly deleted, then it compiles with CL.EXE via godbolt.)

Comment: @C.M. It seems to be a bug. It compiles with the `/std:c++latest` flag

Comment: @JoãoPaulo if this is true -- then it is a language defect. Correct code has to be compiled by every compliant compiler.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/538422/copy-elision-on-lambda-capture.html

Comment: @VladfromMoscow After a quick look I couldn't find anything definitive in C++17 draft. But there are plenty of articles in google that support this claim. They mention "magic of pr-values", where pr-value is not an object but an instance that can materialize into an object. I have no time to support these claims with links to standard.

Comment: @C.M. Copy elision assumes that copying is allowed. Otherwise non-copyable objects would be copyable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, in this case you may have troubles explaining why [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/8rserz) compiles.

Comment: @C.M. Check whether the implicitly declared move constructor is defined by the compiler. Or write S s; auto x = [s = s]{};

Comment: Apparently, Vlad has taken a language-laywer stance and only accepts the notion of "copy elision" as a reference to [class.copy.elision] (which requires copyability or movability), while C.M. actually refers to "guaranteed copy elision", which is an informal term for new prvalue and temporary materialization rules introduced in C++17 (according to them, there is no need to copy or move in the provided example).

Comment: [\[expr.prim.lambda.capture\]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#15) says that _«the non-static data members corresponding to the init-captures are initialized as indicated by the corresponding initializer»_, so the NSDM for `s = S()` is initialized from `= S()`, which is **direct**-initialization by default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per "Language Lawyer"s comment: this is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/538422/copy-elision-on-lambda-capture.html) in MSVC that has been fixed in VS19 v16.2 and VS17 v15.8. Unfortunately (as of now) fix works only with `/std:c++latest`.